# Transaction dropped. How to increase gas fee?

Tags: ether, gas, gas-price

I sent some ether using Ledger Live, but the gas fee was too low. I would like to increase the gas fee. I was told I can do this via Ledger Ethereum Wallet for Chrome. However, when I open Ledger Ethereum Wallet it does not show my transaction.

How can I increase the gas fee?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to send a new transaction with the same nonce and the new gasPrice. Remember, you'll usually be only able to increase gas price, not decrease it.